# How to split sum by month? in googlesheets?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Hello, please help me

How to split sum by month? in googlesheets ?

Comment: Use query and groupby? Maybe a pivot table?

Comment: please give an example...

Comment: If you have a link to a shared worksheet with sample data and your expected output I, or someone else, might. Also, include your own attempt (no matter how small) in your question to make it on topic.

Comment: please https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phY8mL-4AY9TmsgMK42GQPQYnVcHMO8K7WGHv4E-2gM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
    = ArrayFormula(
  { TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());UNIQUE(MONTH(A3:A));DAY(TODAY())); "mmmm yyyy")\ IF(SUMIF(MONTH(A3:A); UNIQUE(MONTH(A3:A));H3:H)=0;;TEXT(SUMIF(MONTH(A3:A); UNIQUE(MONTH(A3:A)); H3:H); "Rp#,###"))})
```

[image]

Comment: thk u so much bro....

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `J3`:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({TEXT(B3:B,"YYYY-MM"),H3:H},"Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2>0 group by Col1 label Col1 'month'"))
```

Comment: We can use `EOMONTH()` to make group of month to sum then can use format clause to show desired date format.

Answer (score 0):

#### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(MONTH(A3:A); UNIQUE(MONTH(A3:A)); H3:H))
```

#### Explanation:

- `MONTH(A3:A)` extracts the month from the dates in column A
- `UNIQUE(MONTH(A3:A))` finds the unique months from this list
- `SUMIF()` takes the month of each row as the range for the summation, the list of unique months as the criteria, and then the total values `H3:H` as the range to sum.
- `ARRAYFORMULA()` expands it to all rows below

Answer (score 0):

Use `QUERY()` function with date columns so that we can sort if needed. Use `EOMONTH()` to make group by month.

```
=QUERY({INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,EOMONTH(B2:B,0))),E2:E},"select Col1,sum(Col2) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1
label Col1 'Month', sum(Col2) 'Total' 
format Col1 'MMM-YYYY'")
```

[image]